# Why is exception.getCause() == exception?

Tags: java

I made a mistake when asking this question by thinking that the value of the member variable `cause` would be returned as the result of a call to `getCause()` in `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException`. That obviously isn't the case. The real cause is returned.

Looking at the source of Throwable I can see that it sets `cause = this` to indicate that the cause has yet to be set. This was a bad question but I did learn something from asking it.

Original question below:

Sometimes when you catch exceptions, the getCause() will return the exception object itself, making it recursive. Why doesn't getCause() return null?

Answer (score 5):

`getCause()` should never return itself unless it's been overridden - if you look at the code for `getCause()` it explicitly returns `null` if the `cause` variable is the same as the throwable you're calling it on.

Which exceptions are you running into which *do* return the same exception again?

Comment: Ah, when debugging I noted that the cause member variable was recursive. However, the getCause() method worked fine. I was catching a org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of when this occurs? The only way I can see that it would happen is if the author called initCause() with the exception itself after construction, and this is very bad practive. I've never seen it.

Comment: Even in this case this shouldn't happen as getCause()'s default implementation is `return (cause==this ? null : cause);`

Comment: ... and initCause(Throwable) checks for `if (cause == this)`

Comment: See comment on Skeet's answer.